# jQuery: как узнать, в какой textarea находится курсор?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть несколько `<textarea>` и наперёд неизвестно, в какой из них будет курсор. Можно ли получить jQuery-объект той `textarea`, в которой на данный момент находится курсор?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно с помощью селектора [:focus](https://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/)

```
$('textarea:focus')
```